# Getting data back from bytes

Tags: android, bluetooth, byte, android-bluetooth, bytestream

I am continuously getting data from remote bluetooth device which I am storing in a buffer `readBuf`.

I copy this `readBuf` to `buf`.

```
System.arraycopy(readBuf, 0, buf, 0, readBuf.length);
```

Now my `buf` contains data such that -

```
buf[0] == 0x7D 

buf[1] == 0x51

buf[2] == 0x42 

...and so on...
```

I want to log this data to know what is coming from remote bluetooth device.

I tried,

```
Log.i(TAG, "Buffer Data---- "+Arrays.toString(buf));
```

But it is not giving data correctly to be `7D 51 42 and so on....`

How to get the data in order to log ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is working fine -

```
    StringBuffer bufData = new StringBuffer();
    for(byte b : readBuf)
    {
        bufData.append(String.format("%02X", b));
        bufData.append(" ");
    }

    Log.i(TAG, "Data Coming from Remote Device---"+bufData.toString());
```

Answer (score 0):

> Arrays.toString(byte[])

Works fine, although what you are seeing is an signed integer representation of each byte. That's because in Java all integers are signed with a [Two's Complement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) .

You can learn a lot on how to convert bytes to hex in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9655181/convert-from-byte-array-to-hex-string-in-java) answer.